# splitting a huge sql file to multiple sql files

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a huge SQL file that I want to restore to mysql server 5.5 .... while I'm restoring the the file at the middle of restoring process stopped, then i got an idea to split that file to several files using java ... is anybody got the  the idea how to split the SQL file into several files .....
the following code  is for the java class that i create to split the SQL file... this class can create for each line in the sql huge file a file"which is not usable", i would like to split the SQL file so i can have files which is able to be restored in the mysql-server

```
import java.io.*;

import java.io.FileWriter;

class DataBase 

{
 public static void main(String args[]){

  try{

  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:/dewiki-20110831-site_stats.sql");

  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String strLine;

  File f;

  int i=1;

  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

        f=new File("D:/myfile"+i+".sql");

  if(!f.exists()){

  f.createNewFile();

  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f));

  out.write(strLine);

  out.close();

  }

  System.out.println (strLine);

  i++;

  }

  in.close();

    }catch (Exception e){

  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());

  }

  }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when file processing is stopped?

Comment: nope, there is no exception actually, it just tell me the process is finished successfully, and when i check the data base there is no table in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there is no need to split the file into several files and store them to the database ...
i found  a way where you can restore the database to mysql which is using mysql commands

here is the command that i used:

mysql - u user_name -p your_password database_name < file_name.sql

it works for me ...

Comment: but the problem is, restoring a big file using the command line takes long time.... is there any suggestion to reduce the time of restoring big database files to mysql server ....

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why the process interrupts halfway through? How are you importing the database?

Just asking because from what I've experienced it's easy to do through the MySQL console or similar using the SOURCE command. At least up to 50-60mb.

Comment: the file that i got is around 2.3 GB .... it's wikipedia dump files ... i would like to restore them to the Mysql server

Comment: @shams, paimoe is right, try using some of the MySQL tools first instead of writing the import tool your self.

Comment: i tried before, some of the files take more than 10 hours just to be restored to the server and others won't be complete restoring to the server.. actually i need the whole data into the server ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mysqldbimport](http://wb.mysql.com/utilities/man/mysqldbimport.html) instead.